# Check string for multiple inputs?

Tags: java

I wanted to know if it was possible to check if a string would have multiple input.
What i did was i made it so when a user input any info it would be stored in a string so i can check for commands.

```
String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
```

Now what i was thinking in order to check if the user has input 5 words or more i would do a for loop such as

```
for(i=0;i<messageSent;i++){}
```

But i'm not sure.

If you don't get what i'm saying then i'm basically asking if i can check if a user has gave me more than 3 input such as
/store blah blah blah blah
and then it will store those too from the string.

Comment: This should be `for(i=0;i<messageSent.length;i++){}` and `for(i=0;i<messageSent;i++){}` will give error

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on the question?  If you have multiple inputs, you obviously have to loop through

Answer (score 0):

> Now what i was thinking in order to check if the user has input 5 words or more i would do a for loop such as

No. Just check the length of the array.

```
String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
if (messageSent.length >= 5) {
    // ...
}
```

And then do something with it based on that.

Answer (score 0):

this looks correct:

```
String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
```

**for this:**
Now what i was thinking in order to check if the user has input 5 words or more i would do a for loop such as

you can check `length` by `messageSent.length`

```
if(messageSent.length >= 5){
 // your logic goes here
}
```

if you want to print:

```
for(i=0;i<messageSent.length;i++){
System.out.println(messageSent[i])
}
```

or even better:

```
for(String msg: messageSent){
System.out.println(msg)
}
```

Hope it helps